# The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i have following problem:

In the title you can read my error message. 
I have in my `layouts/default.vue` an code that checks if i have an cookie stored in this browser.
If its the case, i get the data from the cookie and store it in my `store/index.vue`

```
if (getCookie("jwt") != null) {
    this.$store.commit("storageToken", getCookie("jwt"));
}
```

And in my store i got this code:

```
storageToken: function(state, payload) {
   state.token = payload;
   state.loggedIn = true;
},
```

The problem here is now the `state.loggedIn`. If i set it from false to true, it shows me the error because have in `layouts/default.vue` an `nuxt-link` like this:

```
 <nuxt-link v-if="$store.state.loggedIn" class="loginbtn" to="dashboard">Dashboard</nuxt-link>
```

If i remove my `nuxt-link` tag, the `loggedIn` value gets changed without problems.

I found a way to make it work, if i wrap it in `client-only`.

```
 <client-only>
    <nuxt-link v-if="$store.state.loggedIn" class="loginbtn" to="dashboard">Dashboard</nuxt-link>
 </client-only>
```

It works now, but the problem i have now is a SEO problem. My intern links arent visible for the google crawler now. When i analyze my website it says "could not find any intern links"

So how do i make this work again? I found no answer not here also not on google

Comment: your state should be same on client and server e.g. loggedIn. In your case on server and on client it resolves to different values